# Invalid Plugin for Docker in MacOS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop

After following the documentation for Docker installation in MacOS (Docker Desktop), I received the following error when I tried `docker compose up --build` from https://github.com/LAION-AI/Open-Assistant

```
Invalid Plugins:
  
buildx      failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/macintosh/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx: no such file or directory

compose     failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/macintosh/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose: no such file or directory
  
dev         failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/macintosh/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-dev: no such file or directory
  
extension   failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/macintosh/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-extension: no such file or directory
  
sbom        failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/macintosh/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-sbom: no such file or directory
  
scan        failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /Users/macintosh/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-scan: no such file or directory
```

I cannot find any previous answers that would resolve this issue, how do I solve this error?

I have tried installing manually through curl, but no documentations for MacOS terminals are given (only linuxes). I do not even know the github link for the most updated versions of those plugins.

Comment: When installing docker via Brew, I ran into the same issue. with Docker Desktop this issue didn't appear for me - you may need to go into the Docker Desktop and change some settings (allowing compose v2).

I'm still trying to figure out how to do this without Docker Desktop...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when I updated the Docker Desktop app to the latest version (v4.20.1). After the update, I received an error message "Invalid Plugins" while attempting to run `docker compose`.

In my case, I had Docker Desktop installed on an external storage device, but the error message indicated a path on my internal storage. To resolve this, I followed these steps:

First, delete the local compose file in `/Users/username/.docker/cli-plugins/`

```
rm -rf docker-compose
```

Then, copy the plugin file from the external device `cp /Volumes/External/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugins` to the local plugins folder using the following command:

```
cp /Volumes/External/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugins/docker-compose /Users/username/.docker/cli-plugins
```

You can do the same for the others as well.

After that, you may restart Docker. And that's it.